# Magento 2 language changes not working properly, Only works for first time when i switch

Tags: magento2, session, language

Languages not switching properly. Only works when language parameter `www.website.com/?___store=german` exits into the url but when i click on the other pages then usually parameter will be removed from url then it's not working.

Any idea guys ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a know Magento bug in version 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 (probably 2.1.X as well).

It has been fixed in v. 2.2.2. so you should upgrade.

As a "quick fix", you can change the core file in `/vendor/magento/module-store/block/Switcher.php`

Change the function getTargetStorePostData() to:

```
public function getTargetStorePostData(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store, $data = [])
    {
        $data[\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface::PARAM_NAME] = $store->getCode();
        return $this->_postDataHelper->getPostData(
            //$store->getCurrentUrl(false),
            $this->getUrl('stores/store/switch'),
            $data
        );
    }
```

Comment: I'm on Magento 2.3.5 having the same problem, putting a breakpoint on the function you are referring to does not trigger when debugging, therefore, I don't see how this would work, furthermore, please do not edit core files, as it causes so much pain at the end!

Comment: @HeiderSati This quick fix works only on v. 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 (and some equivalent 2.1.X versions) as it is a Magento bug in those versions and has been fixed in v. 2.2.2+ . You are probably experiencing a different, although similar issue that might be inherent to v. 2.3.5 or your theme. I definitely don't recommend following this answer on any 2.2.2+ version